# Isotope Packery with lazyload.js and tags

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get [Packery.js](https://packery.metafizzy.co) to work with [LazyLoad.js](https://github.com/tuupola/lazyload), while having the ability to filter the gallery by tags.
[www.temp.fokuspunkt.de](https://www.temp.fokuspunkt.de)

On the initial page load everything works fine:
[image]
After clicking throgh the tags and then clicking on the "all" button again, the layout is scrambled, however:
[image]

I assume this has to do with the lazy loading, as it can throw off the layout, as described in the documentation here:
https://packery.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded

Adding the recommended solution

```
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
   $grid.isotope('layout');
});
```

throws an error, though:

[image]

My complete javascript file calling Isotope looks like this, I had tried to copy the above code right beneath the "$(window).on('load',function[...]" function block:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {


    var $grid = $('.isotope-list').packery({
        layoutMode: 'packery',
        filter: '*',
        itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
        gutter: 0,
    });
    
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $grid.packery('layout');
    });

    imagesLoaded( $grid ).on( 'progress', function() {
        pckry.layout();
    });  

    $('.filters li').click(function(){
        //css button styling
        $('.filters li').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        
        // set isotope filter
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
         });
         $grid.packery('layout');
         return false;
    }); 

    var $win = $(window),
        $imgs = $("img"),

    $loadVisible = function($els, trigger) {
        $els.filter(function () {
            var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            return rect.top >= 0 && rect.top <= window.innerHeight;
        }).trigger(trigger);
    }

    $grid.packery('on', 'layoutComplete', function () {
        $loadVisible($imgs, 'lazylazy');
        $grid.packery('layout');
    });

    $win.on('scroll', function () {
        $loadVisible($imgs, 'lazylazy');
    });

    $win.on('resize', function () {
        $grid.packery('layout');
    });

    $imgs.lazyload({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        failure_limit: Math.max($imgs.length - 1, 0),
        event: 'lazylazy'
    });
});
```

I am certain I am doing something stupid, would anybody be kind enough to tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it took a while, but I wanted to return and share my solution. Maybe it helps out somebody else in the future. My main problem was that I used isotope and packery (which is a standalone  library), and not isotope and isotope-packery (which is an addon for isotope). I also changed my lazy loading plugin to "lozad", which makes a lot of thins easier.
In the code below you can also find a solution for using multiple filter terms in combination. In my case I use a row of row of radio buttons below the old button row you can see above.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// initialize Packery
var $pckry = $('.isotope-list').isotope({
    layoutMode: 'packery',
    filter: '*',
    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
    packery: {
        gutter: 0
    },
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    }
});

// layout on first page load, so that the gutter gets set up
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $pckry.isotope('layout');
});

// filter items on button click
$('.filters li').click(function () {
    $('.filters li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    var combinedFilter = getFilter($('.filters li.current').attr('data-filter')) + getFilter($('input[name="isotope-type-filter"]:checked').val().toLowerCase());
    $pckry.isotope({ filter: combinedFilter });
    $pckry.isotope('layout');
});

// filter items on radio button change
$('input[name="isotope-type-filter"]').change(function () {
    var combinedFilter = getFilter($('.filters li.current').attr('data-filter')) + getFilter($('input[name="isotope-type-filter"]:checked').val().toLowerCase());
    $pckry.isotope({ filter: combinedFilter });
    $pckry.isotope('layout');
});

function getFilter(buttonGroup) {
    var filterValue = '';
    if (buttonGroup === '*') {
        filterValue = "";
    } else {
        filterValue = "." + buttonGroup;
    }
    return filterValue;
  };
});
```